# PhoneGap - Native Tabs in Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've create an App for iPhone using PhoneGap and used [NativeControls](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/NativeControls) plugin to create the tabs.

Now, I want to start developing it for Android too but do somebody know if there is a PhoneGap plugin or solution to create the native tabs?

Thanks

Comment: I keep hearing from various devs on the PhoneGap team that it's "coming" as part of PhoneGap itself. However, I don't know if it's using the proper native tabs from Android. I would certainly also love a plugin or functionality to do this. I attempted to do them in html/css/js, but in the end abandoned the idea.

Comment: Even if I design them, I still can't find a way to be fixed on the bottom when you scroll down. It stays only on some devices but not all of them.

Comment: First... bottom? Aren't Android native tabs at the top? Second, you would have to use something like iScroll4 (http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) or something that uses it or something like it (such as the DataZombie fork of jQTouch - https://github.com/DataZombies/jQTouch).

Comment: I know they are at the top but I was talking about making the tabs design myself so I can but them at the bottom like iOS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want it to be like iOS I would suggest using iScroll4 (http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) or even better, the DataZombies fork of jQTouch (https://github.com/DataZombies/jQTouch) that has iScroll4 in it along with an iOS style bottom tab bar all in pure javascript/css.